# Generalized partial fraction decomposistion

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Consider two functions  $ v(x)$ and $u(x)$.

And, you want to break

$$ \frac{1}{u(x) v(x)}.$$

Then, why can't you do $$ \frac{1}{ u(x) v(x)} = \frac{A}{u(x)} + \frac{B}{v(x)},$$ implying

$$ 1 = Av(x) + Bu(x)?$$

And, then put zeros of $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ to solve for constants.

Consider, $(x-b)^3 =v(x)$ and, $ (x-a)^2 = u(x)$. I decomposed this as

$$\frac{1}{(b-a)^2(x-b)^3} +  \frac{1}{(a-b)^3 (x-a)^2}.$$

However this is wrong. Why? I heard it has something to do with poles and all but I haven't done complex analysis yet.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\frac 1 {u(x)v(x)} =\frac  A {u(x)}+\frac  B {v(x)}$ is same as $1=Av(x)+Bu(x)$. If $u$ and $v$ are polynomials then this equation can only hold when $u$ and $v$ are constants. Hence you cannot, in general, find constants $A$ an $B$ so as to satisfy this equation.

Comment: Why does it work only if it polynomials?

Comment: Your partial fraction decomposition is wrong. In your case you have to take $A$ to be a polynomial of degree $2$ and $B$ to be a polynomial of degree $3$. You cannot just take these to be constants.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that one can have the following decomposition$$\frac{1}{u(x)v(x)}=\frac{A}{u(x)}+\frac{B}{v(x)},$$where $A$ and $B$ are constants, implying$$1=Av(x)+Bu(x),$$**only if there exist** constants $A$ and $B$ such that the above relations hold.

So, one cannot conclude that such decomposition always exists for any functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$. Even if $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are polynomials, the latter relation usually does not hold because of degree mismatch of both sides. For example, in your example, $u(x)=(x-a)^2$ and $v(x)=(x-b)^3$, the relation$$1=A(x-b)^3+B(x-a)^2$$ is not correct because the degree of both sides are not equal.